How to prevent OutOfMemoryException in XML to HTML transformation method in C#
I'm using the following method to transform XML data into HTML using an XSLT stylesheet in C#. However, I'm encountering OutOfMemoryException when processing large XML data. How can I optimize this method to handle large XML and XSLT data without running out of memory?
private static string TransformXMLToHTML(string xsltString, string xmlData) {

XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString)))
{
    transform.Load(reader);
}

UTF8StringWriter results = new UTF8StringWriter();

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlData)))
{
    transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
}

return results.ToString(); }

UTF8StringWriter:
public class UTF8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public UTF8StringWriter() { }
    public UTF8StringWriter(IFormatProvider formatProvider) : base(formatProvider) { }
    public UTF8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb) : base(sb) { }
    public UTF8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb, IFormatProvider formatProvider) : base(sb, formatProvider) { }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get
        {
            return Encoding.UTF8;
        }
    }
}

Note: I have referenced other similar questions, few suggested to use file stream but I can't use it here as it will introduce handling file related operations which we can't apply to our entire code base
Edit:
Full Exception:
Exception: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current)
   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(XmlReader input, XsltArgumentList arguments, TextWriter results)
   at CreateMailActivityImpl.TransformXMLToHTML(String xsltString, String xmlData)


Try changing this: transform.Transform(reader, null, results); to this: XmlWriterSettings writerSettings = transform.OutputSettings.Clone();             using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(results, writerSettings))             {                 transform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);             }

Does it have to be string parameters and string result? You could use MemoryStream or a FileStream or even a NetworkStream (if you get it from the web). This is the only reasonable way to avoid huge amounts of memory.

How large are those input/xslt and result strings?

@Charlieface. Yeah the input (Stored in SQL Database) and the output have to be in string type. Since the user environment have different permissions we can't rely on file stream as it needs File related permissions and clean ups.
Does it perform well if we convert the input string to memory stream?

@MartinHonnen The XSLT is around 3200 lines ~0.25 MB and there is no maximum limit for XML data, it is completely dependent on user configuration it can go above few MB

There's not really enough information here to answer your question.  You don't share the XML,  XSLT or traceback so we can't guess where you are running out of memory and suggest alternatives..  You wrote few suggested to use file stream but I can't use it here -- just out of curiosity could you test to see whether using a FileStream for both the inputs and outputs resolves the problem?  And if not could you please [edit] your question to share the full ToString() output of the exception, including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s) if any?

I have added the full exception in the question. And regarding FileStream, no I didn't test that since anyhow we can't implement it right now but based on the suggestions from other references and AI, I can see they are suggesting to do so.

Try XslTransform instead of XslCompiledTransform. This is likely to be slower, but it may well fit into less memory.

This question is similar to: XSLT transformation on Large XML files with C#. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your best bet is to use streams, so that you aren't creating unnecessary strings again and again. You can use for example a FileStream from a file, or a NetworkStream from an HTTP or TCP server. A pre-sized MemoryStream may also be possible, this way you can prevent unnecessary resizing.
private static void TransformXMLToHTML(Stream xslt, Stream xmlData, Stream output)
{
    var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xsltString))
    {
        transform.Load(reader);
    }

    using var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlData);
    using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output);
    transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
}

